# Android - Dialog with different tabs

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-alertdialog

How do I create an alert dialog with different layout tabs?

I tried to create an alert dialog that extends **DialogFragment**, but then I can't extend **tabhost**, so how do I get the tabhost from the dialog layout to do action on the different tabs?